# System.DllNotFoundException: 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xaml, maui

I created a ListView in .NET Maui and a database in SQLite. I want to connect my app to the database but get:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

```
namespace MauiApp1;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite; 


public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    //SQLiteConnection conn;
    //SQLiteCommand cmd;
    //List<int> lstc;
    private void btnsubmit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=D:\Program Files\SQLiteStudio\listview");
        conn.Open();

        var query = "select * from history";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);

        List<int> lstc = new List<int>();

        while (reader. Read())
        {
            lstc.Add(dt.Rows.Count);

        }

        lstx.ItemsSource = lstc;
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

I added more than 5 NugetPackage but couldn't solve it.

Comment: please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

This error indicates that `System.Data.Sqlite` doesn't include a native interop library. Alternatively, you can use the [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli).

I create a dummy database: **hello.db** to test it. It works on my side.
Here's the sample code for your reference:

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\...\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\hello.db"))
      {
            connection.Open();
            var command1 = connection.CreateCommand();
            command1.CommandText =
            @"
                    CREATE TABLE user (
                        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        name TEXT NOT NULL
                    );
                    INSERT INTO user
                    VALUES (1, 'Brice'),
                           (2, 'Alexander'),
                           (3, 'Nate');
                ";
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText =
            @"
                    SELECT name
                    FROM user
                   
                ";
   
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var name = reader.GetString(0);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
                }
            }
            connection.Close(); 
      }  
}
```

For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli.